# ffplay real-time buffer too full or near too full - frame dropped

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to replace a proprietary video player with ffplay on a Windows 10 workstation. The requirement is that I use a Decklink Mini Recorder card, the video size is 1280x720P, is borderless and opens at a specific position on the screen.

[image: Errors]

The video overlays on another app called iControl that changes the video input of the Decklink card. I have this working as a batch file:

```
@echo off
ffplay -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -left 631 -top 19 -rtbufsize 75000K -framerate 59.94 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -noborder -hide_banner -alwaysontop
```

This works great for about 8 to 10 hours but then starts spitting out real-time buffer errors that the video input is too full or near too full and frames start dropping. I can't increase the buffer size as it causes lip sync issues after a few hours. I saw in another post that this was fixed in ffmpeg with a `thread_queue_size` parameter, but that option does not appear to be available for ffplay and I can't figure out how to use ffmpeg to open a video window with no border, and at a specific X/Y coordinate on the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: It could be some kind of "clock drift", were the inaccuracy of the timestamps keeps raising. For testing, try only video without audio.  In case it's not working, try displaying the video as soon as possible using `setpts=0` filter: `ffplay -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -left 631 -top 19 -rtbufsize 75000K -framerate 59.94 -i video="Decklink Video Capture" -vf setpts=0 -noborder -hide_banner -alwaysontop`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you *must* use FFPLAY, update it to the latest version. However, if there is a memory leak in the application, then you, as a user, cannot fix that issue. Developers would need to fix it, and make a new release.
2. If you have an option to switch players, try some of the *many* good, free, Windows players, such as [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/), [mpc-hc](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases) or a [plethora of alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/vlc-media-player/). My experience is that the first two, and probably many others, do not have memory issues.
3. A possibility is that Windows OS is not reallocating memory from its [Standby List](https://superuser.com/questions/1579851/what-is-standby-memory-in-ms-windows-os) expeditiously. You could try a tools such as WagnardSoft's free [Intelligent standby list cleaner (ISLC)](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/ISLCw) to speed memory reallocation. Though it is intended to improve gameplay, I've found it useful for other memory-intensive tasks, such as file conversion and transferring large amounts of data to an e-reader. There is no installation needed, so it's easy to test if it would help.